# Django User Groups

Tags: django

I read about creating user groups, I think I have the general idea.

For instance if I have these two statement:

`customer_group= Group(name='Customer')`

`customer_group.save()`

Where in my django Project should I include the above statement to define the customer_group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should just create one such group through `admin` or through `django shell`. You don't want to create multiple Customer groups, right?

Comment: Right now I am creating the groups through the shell, However isn't there a way to write a "script" that would initialize the groups. I just look at the the shell as great way to test out method but its not a solution.

Comment: Yes, you can provide initial data for models: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically create groups and minimize the manual part of the process, you can use fixtures (deprecated as of version 1.7), migrations (as of version 1.7) or a post_syncdb signal to populate the database.  I chose the later, and posted details on [how to use a post_syncdb signal to populate Django security groups](http://www.geekrant.org/2014/04/19/programmatically-create-django-security-groups/).  The upshot of this is that any time that your application's `syncdb` command is run the groups will be created.